# Условия обособления определений, стоящих после определяемого слова

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, определения

"Не обособляются распространенные определения, стоящие после определяемого существительного, если последнее само по себе в данном предложении не выражает нужного смысла и нуждается в определении.", - Розенталь.

1) Среди цветов, **красивых, свежих**, я увидел что-то блестящее.

Если убрать оборот, то смысл не изменится.

2) Анна обиделась и приняла вид **довольно строгий и пугающий**.

Если убрать оборот, предложение перестанет нести нужную смысловую нагрузку, нам не будет понятно, что происходит.

3) Он находился в состоянии, **похожем на лихорадочный бред или на состояние пьяного человека**.

Если убрать оборот, то проблематично будет понять смысл, однако запятая ставится. Интуитивно понятно, что запятая должна ставится, но четкого разграничения нет.

4) Он находился в доме **интересном и загадочном**.
   Среди детей **умных и подготовленных** был Иван.

Кажется, здесь опять самая неприятная вещь в языке - смысл. В этом предложении упор делается не на факт нахождения в доме, а на его облик. А во втором предложении - на качества детей, а не на факт их отношения к этой возрастной группе. И дети не все были умными, следовательно, нельзя обособить оборот.

Как можно понять, когда это правило применяется точно? Особенно интересуют случаи, похожие на 3. 
Наверное, все дело в причастиях. Логическое ударение при причастных оборотах падает на определяемое слово. (Она приняла вид, похожий на сорняк. Она приняла какой-то там вид, но нас интересует именно то, что он похож на что-то).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Особенности решения:**

1) При обособлении оборота мы имеем **две ситуации**, а в простом неосложненном предложении **одна ситуация:**

*Среди цветов, **красивых, свежих**, я увидел что-то блестящее.* (1) Среди цветов я увидел что-то блестящее. (2) Цветы были  красивые, свежие.

Вторая ситуация (при обособлении оборота) является **дополнительным сообщением** о предмете, но если оборот не обособляется, то он входит в основное сообщение как **важный смысловой элемент**.

2) Обычно слова **с неопределенным значением** требуют определения: *Анна обиделась и приняла вид довольно строгий и пугающий.*

3) При обособлении **ударение падает** на определяемое слово и на обособленный оборот, при отсутствии обособления ― только на оборот. Поэтому оборот  **выделяется по смыслу и приобретает особую значимост**ь. *Он находился в доме интересном и загадочном.* Сравнить: *Он находился в старом доме,  интересном и загадочном.*

*Среди детей умных и подготовленных был (мальчик по имени) Иван.* Выделена группа умных детей. Описана одна ситуация.

*Среди детей, умных и подготовленных, был (мальчик по имени) Иван*. Все дети были умные. Описаны две ситуации.

4) *Он находился в состоянии, похожем (которое было похоже) на лихорадочный бред или на состояние пьяного человека.* По структуре это аналог придаточного предложения.

Слово "состояние" требует определения, **но структура предложения не позволяет перенести ударение на оборот.** Сравнить: *Он находился в состоянии лихорадочном и беспокойном.*

**Вывод:** При решении таких задач надо пользоваться интонационно-структурным анализом, а  также учитывать смысловую составляющую высказывания.

Answer (score 0):

Существуют грамматические правила, которые диктуют то, после определяемого слова размещать определение или перед. Например, определения, состоящие из одного слова, ставятся перед определяемым словом. Если вы скажете не: ‟К дому подъехала красная машина”, а: ‟К дому подъехала машина красная”, то носитель языка заметит нарушение грамматической нормы. Подобное нарушение грамматической нормы о порядке слов в предложении называется инверсией. Чаще всего инверсия используется в стихотворениях для сохранения рифмы.

Все эти примеры в пункте у Розенталя как раз с такой инверсией, где определение должно стоять перед определяемым словом, но размещается после определяемого слова. Вот несколько из них:

> Дмитриевна приняла вид достойный и несколько обиженный. Должно быть: ‟Дмитриевна приняла достойный и несколько обиженный вид”.
>
> Попытки писать просто приводили к результатам печальным и смешным. Должно быть: ‟Попытки писать просто приводили к печальным и смешным результатам”.

Что касается формулировки Розенталя по этому вопросу (‟если последнее само по себе в данном предложении не выражает нужного смысла и нуждается в определении”), то я не думаю, что в ней вообще есть какой-то смысл.